# Cannot install xlrd 0.7.8 for python 2.7.3

Tags: python, windows-7, installation, xlrd

I can't find anything around for current versions around, but my issue is exactly as the title says. Python is installed and working, but when I tried using the instructions listed on to install xlrd (open cmd at the setup directory, then enter "python setup.py install"), but this gives me an error saying that the command python doesn't exist. Double clicking the setup file doesn't work, the black cmd box flashes on the screen rapidly, without time to read what it says and without installing any files in the directories they should be in.

Also, as it may be relevant, I don't have permissions on this computer to install programs (the IT dept had to install python and N++ for me...). I don't know if this counts as a software installation that requres elevation, as far as Windows 7 is concerned.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I think you want to post that question in the "super user" site, not in stackoverflow.

Comment: I didnt even know that existed, ive only been on here 2 days. I'll remember that though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your command interpreter tells you the "command python doesn't exist" whereas it is installed it means it is not in your PATH environment variable.

Here is a little tutorial on how to do this on windows 7: http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2010/05/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7/

Add the path where your python.exe is. Usually something like *C:\Python27*

Comment: Thats all it took! I always forget about that thing, i wish it was automatic :p Thank you